# MongoDB PyMongo: return document count for each month for a mm/dd/YYYY articledate field

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a MongoDB collection with around 20K articles with an "articledate" string field with dates in the "dd/mm/YYYY" format.

Want to query the collection and get the sum of the count of articles in each mm/YYYY.

This is the pipeline I have written which should also handle the date format:

```
# Aggregation pipeline to group documents by year and month and count them
pipeline = [
    {"$match": {"articledatepub": {"$exists": True}}},
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "date_object": {
                "$dateFromString": {"dateString": "$articledatepub", "format": "%m/%d/%Y"}
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "year": {"$year": "$date_object"},
                "month": {"$month": "$date_object"},
            },
            "count": {"$sum": 1},
        }
    },
    {"$sort": {"_id.year": 1, "_id.month": 1}},
]
```

but when I execute it the result is empty:

```
# Execute the aggregation pipeline
result = list(articles.aggregate(pipeline))
```

Here is a small fictional sample of the data:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "641dddcd685f9e1cbbc73490"
  },
  "articleid": 2003287422,
  "articledatepub": "23/03/2023"
}
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "641dddcd685f9e1cccc73490"
  },
  "articleid": 2003283422,
  "articledatepub": "22/03/2023"
}
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "641dddcd687f9e1cccc73490"
  },
  "articleid": 2003383422,
  "articledatepub": "11/02/2023"
}
```

from which I'd expect a count of two articles for March 2023 and one for February 2023.

Comment: Please add some input data

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the `format` parameter of [`$dateFromString`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) to `"%d/%m/%Y"`. Try this:

```
pipeline = [
    {"$match": {"articledatepub": {"$exists": True}}},
    {"$project": {"date_object": {
        "$dateFromString": {"dateString": "$articledatepub", "format": "%d/%m/%Y"}}}},
    {"$project": {"year": {"$year": "$date_object"}, "month": {"$month": "$date_object"}}},
    {"$group": {"_id": {"year": "$year", "month": "$month"}, "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
    {"$sort": {"_id.year": 1, "_id.month": 1}},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above would not work because of the DD/MM/YYYY format.

Here is the working code which parses that date format "manually" with a revised pipeline:

```
pipeline = [
    {"$match": {"articledatepub": {"$exists": True}}},
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "date_object": {
                "$dateFromString": {
                    "dateString": {
                        "$concat": [
                            {"$substr": ["$articledatepub", 6, 4]},  # Year
                            "-",
                            {"$substr": ["$articledatepub", 0, 2]},  # Month
                            "-",
                            {"$substr": ["$articledatepub", 3, 2]},  # Day
                        ]
                    },
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "year": {"$year": "$date_object"},
                "month": {"$month": "$date_object"},
            },
            "count": {"$sum": 1},
        }
    },
    {"$sort": {"_id.year": 1, "_id.month": 1}},
]
```